# Handset and Website Authentication

Tags: android, ios, authentication, mobile, web-applications

I am making a webapp which will coordinate with an iOS and Android application. There will be a two types of accounts. One will be primarily on the website and the other will be primarily on the Android or iOS app. This question may be too broad, but I'm looking for an authentication pattern which will work for this setup and make sure that the right web account is pairing with the right mobile account. Here's what I've got so far and am hoping you can provide some feedback...

When a mobile app is installed, it will reach out to the server with information such as name and phone number to which a UUID will be returned.

If the web account wants to link with a mobile account, the web account must enter the phone number of the mobile app they want to link to. The server then sends a message to the mobile device so that user can confirm the pairing.

Are there drawbacks to basing the account id on a phone number? Is there a better way to do such two factor authentication? Sorry if this is too vague or undirected and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Phone number is a bad UUID because there is no way to get the phone number.  Other than asking the user.  Not reliably.  Also, some devices allow dual sims (home and work) and thus would have multiple phone numbers.

A better way is to use the android device id.  But even that isn't that great-  I could write an app that calls your service with whatever id I want.  There's a reason RSA keys use a cryptographic token that changes every minute-  it requires you not only to know the id, but to know what the id is now.  Otherwise you'd just need to have found out the secret id once and you're in for life.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what would you recommend I use instead? Also I was contemplating having the phone reach out to the server and the server returns a generated random UUID which will then be used for further communication instead of the phone number. The phone number would just be used as one identifier for one account to link to the other. I need a way for the web account to say "I want to connect with that user over there on the mobile app" and am not sure which way would be the easiest to ensure this.